# laravel 8 - Spatie activity log v3 - call to undefined method App\Models\Report::user()

Tags: laravel-8

I am using [spatie activity-log v3](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v3/introduction) to log activities done by users in the website.

In the `User.php` Model, I have the following code (which works correctly)

```
use App\Core\Traits\SpatieLogsActivity;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    use SpatieLogsActivity, LogsActivity;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * Log all activities performed by the user.
    */
    protected static $ignoreChangesAttributes = ['password'];
    protected static $logAttributes = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'avatar'];
    protected static $spatieLogsActivity = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'avatar'];
    protected static $recordEvents = ['created', 'updated', 'deleted'];
    protected static $logName = 'Users';

...
```

The code above, means I want spatie to track the `'name', 'email', 'phone', 'avatar'` inputs when the user `'created', 'updated', 'deleted'` them.

I am trying to implement the same functionality for another model: `Report`

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Core\Traits\SpatieLogsActivity;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SpatieLogsActivity, LogsActivity;
    use HasRoles;

     /**
     * Log all activities performed by the user.
    */
    protected static $ignoreChangesAttributes = [''];
    protected static $spatieLogsActivity = ['caseType', 'caseLocation'];
    protected static $recordEvents = ['created', 'updated', 'deleted'];
    protected static $logName = 'Reports & Cases';
```

When I do some changes in the `Report` form and refresh the audit log, it shows me an error:

[image]

**However!**, when I delete previously inserted data and refresh, the log will actually show:

[image]

Comment: can you copy the related error log from `storage/logs` so we can get a little more context?

Answer (score 0):

I just added the block of code in `Report` Model

```
/**
* Get a fullname combination of first_name and last_name
*
* @return string
*/
public function getNameAttribute()
{
 return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

what I understood from the error is that the log cannot find the user aka causer of the events in the Report model.